# Magento on Wamp Not Showing Administrator Permissions

Tags: magento, wamp, wampserver

i am working on local system on WAMPSERVER 2.0 and I am installing the magento 1.6.2.0 and when i go to the System -> Permissions -> Roles and click on Administrators I got page broken screen. I have tried to change the max execution time, memory limit in php.ini etc but nothing works.

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Please set php's "display_errors" to "On" in your php.ini or your .htaccess and post the errors.

Comment: @KristianHildebrandt I have resolved it by changed a function in core files. I am posting in answer

Comment: @Hanan Ali can you post your changes. I can't imagine an edit to the core is the correct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made changes in the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php
Search function getRowUrl in the file.

```
public function getRowUrl($item)
{
$res = parent::getRowUrl($item);
return ($res ? $res : '#');
}
```

Replace this function with below function:

```
public function getRowUrl($item)
{
$res = parent::getUrl($item);
return ($res ? $res : '#');
}
```

It worked for me and resolved my issue. I know its not good to made changes in core files but i was working on local system and was stuck for this.

Regards,
Hanan Ali